# Reply to amazon buyers on behalf of sellers

Tags: amazon-mws

I am developing a web-application for amazon sellers, which sends emails to their customers.

the problem I am facing now is that the emails I am sending are not authorized by amazon to contact the buyers even though I have mws permissions. 
sending such a message result a notification at the seller account saying "An unknown sender is attempting to communicate with your customers through the Buyer-Seller Messaging Service. We currently have 1 undelivered messages that will not be sent unless this sender is approved. Please visit the alternate address approval page to fix this."

I know for a fact that there are mws services that reply on behalf of sellers and there's no notification or anything special , the mws access is probably enough so I guess I am doing something wrong.

I was replying with my development amazon account . Does anyone know what might be the reason for that notification ?

Comment: Are those "MWS Services replying on behalf of sellers" using their own "from" email address, or are they sending the emails pretending it is coming from the sellers email address?

Comment: to be honest I am not sure. I will need to check it - but I get your point. thanks

Comment: Do you know if  there is any api to get and reply to messages in amazon seller central?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

You should add email address that you are using to reply to the Approved senders in Alternate address section of the Amazon Seller Central https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/communication-manager/address-authorization.html

Basically you can't send an email to Amazon customers from ANY email address. You can do it only as a seller from address registered in Seller Central.

Comment: Currently there is no other way. There are 3 options. Reply yourself from Seller Central web interface. Use your email with Outlook etc. Use 3rd party solution which will get messages by email anyway. The problem is that Amazon MWS doesn't provide anything for buyers messages. You can't get them or reply to them using Amazon MWS API.